# Navigating to jquery child tabs in different file

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have tab named *Setup*. When I click *Setup* it displays two links "Bank" and "Software" in the content. Setup also has sub-tabs *Banks* and *Software*. When the links are clicked it should go the respective tabs but in different files. For better understanding I have attached the plunker link:

https://plnkr.co/edit/7tGam9FJUREXLk1TCvaR?p=preview

Below is the jQuery I used to call the respective tabs. It is not working.

```
<script>
    $('#setup').tabs();
    $('#banks').click(function(){
         $('#setup').tabs("option","active",0);
    });

    $('#software').click(function(){
    $('#setup').tabs("option","active",1);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: At the plunker you're importing bootstrap and not jquery-ui, which of both are you using? (one tag says is jquery-ui)

Comment: @JoseRojas  .tabs() is a function in jquery-ui so I added it now in plunker..

Comment: @Sindhu I do not see `.tabs()` being used in your plunker. If you did not want to use the, can just execute the same action for the sub-menus as the links.

Comment: @twisty i used .tabs in setup.html